# Rails 4: nested content_tag in methods and blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I think I have created a bit of a nasty problem for myself. See below:

**View**

```
<% tl = tablist_initialize(params[:tab], 'profile') %>

# lots of html
# ...

<%= tl.tab_content do %>
    <% tl.tab_panel 'profile' do %>
        Hello!
    <% end %>
    <% tl.tab_panel 'settings' do %>
      Sup!
    <% end %>
    <% tl.tab_panel 'notifications' do %>
      Nothing!
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Helper**

```
class TabList
    include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
    attr_accessor :output_buffer

    def initialize(tab, primary)
      @current_tab = tab
      @primary = primary
    end

    def tab_content(&block)
        content_tag(:div, :class => "tab-content", &block)
    end

    def tab_panel(id, &block)
        concat(content_tag(:div, {:class => (@current_tab == id ? "tab-pane active" : "tab-pane"),
          :role => "tabpanel", :id => id }, &block))
    end

    # other methods
    # ...
end
```

**Output**

My plan here, is to create bootstrap tab easily. The result is now like this:

```
Hello! Sup! Nothing!
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="profile">
         Hello!
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="settings">
        Sup!
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="notifications">    
        Nothing!
    </div>
</div>
```

Why the first line of the result (Hello! Sup! Nothing!)? I think it is strange that is outputs the inner block(s) two times: once right and once totally outside of either blocks (in the beginning). I tried different approaches: omitting the concat function, using concat around yield in the first content_tag, but all of these attempts did not give me the wished result.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the = on your tl.tab_content line and add an = on each of your tl.tabl_panel lines.

```
<% tl.tab_content do %>
    <%= tl.tab_panel 'profile' do %>
        Hello!
    <% end %>
    <%= tl.tab_panel 'settings' do %>
      Sup!
    <% end %>
    <%= tl.tab_panel 'notifications' do %>
      Nothing!
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also, remove `concat` from your tab_panel method.

```
class TabList
include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
attr_accessor :output_buffer

def initialize(tab, primary)
  @current_tab = tab
  @primary = primary
end

def tab_content(&block)
    content_tag(:div, :class => "tab-content", &block)
end

def tab_panel(id, &block)
    content_tag(:div, {:class => (@current_tab == id ? "tab-pane active" : "tab-pane"), :role => "tabpanel", :id => id }, &block)
end

# other methods
# ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for update, but that didn't do the trick either. http://pastie.org/10739099 It still prints the inner block content several times, and it emits the outer div with tab-content class.